# MongoDB warn about query not using index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a vague memory that MongoDB will output to its log a message if a query uses fields that are not indexed, however I am unable to reproduce this locally (with an admittedly small dataset) nor have I found any documentation for it.

Am I imagining things or is there such a feature? If yes, can anyone link to documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to turn on profiling to get a meaningful log from mongodb - setting profiling to 1 is sufficient.

You can then find unindexed queries using any number of searches in the log, e.g.:

```
grep nscanned /path/to/mongodb.log | grep -v "nscanned:1 " | grep -v "nscanned:0 "
```

Original tweet where I found out about this: https://twitter.com/#!/eonwhite/status/21498320559

You can see more about what the log output means  [in mongo's docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler)

> If nscanned is much higher than nreturned, the database is scanning many objects to find the target objects. Consider creating an index to improve this.

Comment: In addition to this check out http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler#DatabaseProfiler-ViewingtheData - it explains the various data you can look at in the profiler.  The --slowms option can be used to lower the thrreshold that a query is considered slow too, to let you get a look at more operations that aren't using indexes.

Answer (score 4):

You might be thinking of the `notablescan` [parameter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.notablescan) and [configuration option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#notablescan). However, it's not a warning or logging feature. Instead, it causes the server to throw an error whenever a query is made for which there is no useful index (forcing the server to scan the entire collection).

Answer (score 3):

perhaps you are referring to the "explain" functionality?

see this link: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain

Basically, you can tell Mongo to give you extra data when you run a query, that data including details about whether or not an index was used.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no direct signs of it in the log or anywhere else. Indirectly missing indexes can result in these log entries:

- `warning: ClientCursor::yield can't unlock b/c of recursive lock` - usually happens with `findAndModify`.
- `query db.coll nscanned:656204 reslen:20 5305ms` - slow query with big number of scanned documents.

Neither of above will show up if the corresponding queries execute fast enough.

Comment: "5305ms" looks like a pretty direct sign of a slow/unindexed query to me =)