# How to optimize find by date query in mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, query-optimization, pymongo, nosql

I have a collection with 0.6 millions of documents. Mostly the documents are structured like below,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53d86ef920ba274d5e4c8683"),
    "checksum" : "2856caa9490e5c92aedde91330964488",
    "content" : "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"bn-bd\" lang=\"bn-bd\" dir=\"ltr\" " />\n  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/templates/beez_20/css/position.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen,projection\ef=\"/index.php/bn/contact-bangla/2013-0</body>\r\n</html>",
    "date" : ISODate("2014-07-29T15:57:11.886Z"),
    "filtered_content" : "",
    "indexed" : true,
    "category": 'raw',
    "link_extracted" : 1,
    "parsed" : true,
    "title" : "Constituency 249_10th_En",
    "url" : "http://www.somesite.com.bd/index.php/bn/bangla/2014-03-23-11-45-04?layout=edit&id=2143"
}
```

All the documents have the *date* attribute with them. Now when I write the query below I get an indefinite time of delay to display the result.

```
from pymongo import Connection
import datetime

con = Connection()
db = con.spider
pages = db.pages

today = datetime.datetime.combine( datetime.date.today(), datetime.datetime.min.time() )

c = pages.find({ u'category': 'news', u'date': {u'$gt': today } }, {u'title': 1, '_id': 0} )

for item in c:
    print item
```

Indexes are,

```
_id, url, parsed
```

How can I improve the performance for this query limiting to an acceptable amount of time? Any solid answer, suggestions is appreciated!

Comment: Is that your only index? Do you have an index on date?

Comment: just starting out with mongodb. A bit skeptical about more indexes. No I don't have index on date.

Comment: One thing you can do during local development is to configure your mongodb to fail a query if it does not use an index. Or maybe it just lists such queries in the log: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191615/mongodb-warn-about-query-not-using-index That will allow you to ensure that your queries run as fast as possible. You can also look at finding a minimal subset of indexes that satisfy your queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like adding an index on `category` and `date` would help.

```
pages.createIndex({'date': 1, 'category': 1});
```

In pymongo, [the index creation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index) would look more like this:

```
keys = [
    ("date", pymongo.ASCENDING),
    ("category", pymongo.ASCENDING)
]
pages.create_index(keys)
```

The most likely options you would be interested in are:

```
name: custom name to use for this index - if none is given, a name will be generated
unique: if True creates a unique constraint on the index
```

I don't expect that date/category would be unique, though. Giving the index a name seems a good practice.

Comment: hugh, does it increase memory size in a large scale?

Comment: @Dewsworld MongoDB always takes as much memory as it can get. So when you are panicking because your DB server already uses all of its RAM, rest assured that this is the case no matter what you do. This is by design.

Comment: @hughbrown worked like a charm! Please add a colon after pages.createIndex({'date': 1, 'category'